# Screen content showing for a few seconds before screensaver starts (Fedora 14)

Tags: fedora, screensaver, screen-lock

This happens every now and then, I have not pinned down the cause but let me describe the symptoms.

On occasion when I come back to the computer after a few hours the screen is in energy saving mode, I touch the mouse, or the keyboard and I see the screen as it was when I left it. Then, a few seconds later the screen dims to black and the screen saver turns on, moving the mouse again brings me to the login page to unlock the screen.

This seems to be a security flaw since unauthorised users can see my screen...

Anyone seen this happen to them?

I'm using Fedora 14 2.6.35.14-95.fc14.i686PAE

Cheers.

Comment: Posting the name of your screensaver program and desktop environment would be helpful.

Comment: If this is a bug in your screen-saver, there's no way you're going to get a fix from Fedora, because you're running a version of Fedora that was was end of life December 8th, 2011.

Answer (score 1):

Your screen lock time is longer than your low-power time, hence your system doesn't technically lock until *after* it's gone into low-power mode. However, since your system is in low-power mode it *can't* lock but instead locks at the earliest possible time, which would be once it has been woken back up.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using `xscreensaver`, which does the same for me.

If this concerns you, you may want to try another screen lock utility,
`xlock` springs into mind for example.

`xscreensaver` has this feature for me on Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04 and on Fedora 17,
all running `lxde` and the `awesome` window manager.