After mate-screensaver blacks screen, input causes screen contents to be visible for a few seconds before showing unlock prompt
I regularly observe this behaviour on one particular system:

I lock the screen either manually or by idling for the configured time
screen turns black and shortly after the screen enters power-save
I try to unlock it by pressing a key or moving the mouse
screen turns on, but without the screen lock, showing the regular desktop

I can move the mouse and see the cursor move
windows display a fresh image (not the one when the screen should have locked)


after a few seconds something remembers that the screen was to be locked and then hides the regular desktop and shows the password prompt
entering the correct password then correctly unlocks the screen

I have never seen this before and I run basically the same setup on most of my systems, past and present. And I have not seen this happen with the same system on a different physical screen.
This is currently more of a nuisance but I worry about it also being a security problem. Potentially this might allow people without the correct credentials to unlock the system permanently.
The system is set up as this:

Linux kernel 6.7.12
debian trixie/sid
lightdm
mate as session manager
mate-screensaver (default)
xmonad as window manager (replacing marco in mate)
LG screen and a (somewhat older) AMD/ATI Radeon card

I suspect lightdm mate-screensaver to be the culprit but I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I also have only observed this with the specific LG screen, but what the system decides to display in this context should theoretically not depend on what screen is plugged in.

what is actually locking the screen? xscreensaver, xlock, lxlock...?

@Lutz I think mate-screensaver seeing as none of the others are installed and mate-screensaver seems to be running in the background.

I found https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wcwv-5qmw-xfpj - so next question is what version of mate-screensaver is it?

you could try to install xscreensaver, remove mate-screensaver (either from the system or just fro the session) and start xscreensaver instead.

have you looked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22026/screen-content-showing-for-a-few-seconds-before-screensaver-starts-fedora-14?rq=1 ?

@Lutz Thank you. Yes, that github advisory sounds about right, but my distro's shipping mate-screensaver 1.26.2. I saw that other question you found but determined that the answers do not apply because the lock-time was not configured to be after the low-power time. And I was not running xscreensaver.
